# Windows CMD prompt for Youtube-Dl. Cant download multiple youtube mp3 playlists, into specific folders

Tags: audio, download, youtube, command-prompt, youtube-dl

Im currently having some trouble executing this command in youtube dl:

```
youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 -i '%(playlist)s/%(playlist_index)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s' <here is where i would usually put the link>
```

Basically, I use the following command: `youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-format -i <youtube link>`. It always works without a hitch and downloads the playlist.

I have a bunch of playlists that I want to download, but I don't want to manually download each and everyone: My goal is to get all of my youtube playlists, download them with one command and make youtube dl somehow create an individual folder for each playlist, bearing the same name as the playlist...

PS: this is the error code that I receive upon entering the very first command.

```
C:\youtube-dl> youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 '%(playlist)s/%(playlist_index)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s' -i https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuE_hO-7ktGpcYuoeE9o8w-2MWEkKu5zK

WARNING: The url doesn't specify the protocol, trying with http
[generic] %(playlist_index)s: Requesting header

WARNING: Could not send HEAD request to http://'%(playlist)s/%(playlist_index)s: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>
[generic] %(playlist_index)s: Downloading webpage

ERROR: Unable to download webpage: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed> (caused by URLError(gaierror(11001, 'getaddrinfo failed'),))

ERROR: '-' is not a valid URL. Set --default-search "ytsearch" (or run  youtube-dl "ytsearch:-" ) to search YouTube

ERROR: "%(title)s.%(ext)s'" is not a valid URL. Set --default-search "ytsearch" (or run  youtube-dl "ytsearch:%(title)s.%(ext)s'" ) to search YouTube

[youtube:playlist] PLuE_hO-7ktGpcYuoeE9o8w-2MWEkKu5zK: Downloading webpage
```

Answer (score 0):

The Windows `cmd` shell interprets percent signs, even in single quotes (`'`). Put them in double quotes (`"`). On top of this, you are missing the `-o` option. You want:

`youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 -o "%(playlist)s/%(playlist_index)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s" -i "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuE_hO-7ktGpcYuoeE9o8w-2MWEkKu5zK"`

To find these kinds of problems yourself in the future, pass in `-v` right after youtube-dl and check that the outputted command line is the one you expect.

Comment: If this - or any other - answer solves your problem, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/141962). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you forgot the "-o" switch before your output template.